# assign value to textarea from the previous page input using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, textarea

I want to fetch the value from my previous page,and assign it to my textarea in the current page,using javascript. I wrote down the following code,but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base="<%=text%>"; 
var send=document.getElementbyId('code1');
base.value=send.value;
</script>    

<%
String text;
text=request.getParameter("code");
out.println(text);  
%>

<textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="code1" id="code1">
</textarea>
```

The value is successfully retrieved in the String text, but isn't assigned to the textarea. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="code1" id="code1">
<%=request.getParameter("code")%>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Even better. Why bother with the JavaScript at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely what's going on here but I reckon you'd want something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var send=document.getElementbyId('code1');
send.value = "<%=text%>";
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work...
even if I simply do:

`<script type="text/javascript">

var send=document.getElementbyId('code1');

send.value = "abc";

</script> 


<textarea rows="20" cols="100" name="code1" id="code1">

</textarea>`

Comment: if you have to use JavaScript, what if you put the javascript at the bottom of the page? The TextArea won't be in the DOM if the javascript is above.

Comment: Javascript executes when the page loads,whether you put it at the bottom or at the top,it doesn't matter..

Comment: Au contraire. It does you know.